# Пространство имен в php . Как вызвать метод класса который находится в соседней папке?

Tags: php, ооп

начал изучать ООП и столкнулся с трудностью .
Есть папка app , в ней лежат еще две папки , controllers и models , в controllers лежит файл UsersController.php , а в модели UsersModel.php

Я в контроллере пытаюсь вызвать метод sign класса usersmodel , но выдает ошибку " Uncaught Error: Class ... not found"

В контроллере прописано "use app\Models\UsersModel" IDE подствечивает что все хорошо , но данные не передаются . Не пойму что не так .

File UsersController.php :

```
    namespace app\controllers;

use app\Models\UsersModel;

class UsersController
{
        public function signUP()
        {
           $test2 = new UsersModel();
           $test2->sign("testvalue");
           

        }


}
```

File UsersModel.php

```
namespace app\Models;

class UsersModel
{
    public function sign($userData)
    {
        var_dump($userData);
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуй `use \app\Models\UsersModel` с обратным слэшем перед

Comment: @DmitryKozlov , " Uncaught Error: Class 'app\Models\UsersModel' not found in" Не получилось :(

Comment: а автозагрузку-то сделал?  просто расположить файлы по папкам и писать неймспейсы - не достаточно

Comment: надо использовать загрузчик классов ещё ....либо https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php   либо  через композер......... либо  инклудить файл вручную))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , у меня есть файл composer.json , 
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4":{
        "app\\": "app/"
    }
  }
}
Вот что прописано в нем .

Comment: а сделал потом composer install ?))  а require '../vendor/autoload.php';  сделал?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да ) Может я куда-то не туда прикрепил его ? Я его прикрепил в Index.php через require_once

Comment: ну в индекс норм. главное чтобы правильно путь указать...и не забыть install сделать ....)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , да  , не туда прикрепил . Решил проблему , спасибо за помощь